# Duncan Leading Indicator definition & source of origin

Tags: indicator

What is the official definition of the Duncan Leading Indicator? I've looked at all links page after page on google but can't seem to find any official source of origin and therefore official definition, only third party articles which claim some definition.

And which Duncan is the original creator behind the indicator?

Comment: According to this 1985 newsletter it was "proposed in recent years by Professor Wallace Duncan of Northern Arizona University" https://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/el85-17.pdf

Comment: And the origin may be this article in Federal Reserve of Dallas Review, *Business Cycles : A New Leading Indicator* by Wallace Duncan (1977) https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/review-federal-reserve-bank-dallas-5730/march-1977-575871/business-cycles-525768

Comment: But it does not seem on topic for Quant Stackexchange, maybe try Economics Stackexchange.

Comment: @nbbo2 thank you!